# Как сделать непрозрачный фон для TextView

Tags: android, android-textview

См. картинку. [image: картинка]

Как сделать,что бы линия ячейки (это editText) не перечеркивала фон TextView? Спасибо.

my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1280dp"
    android:layout_height="720dp">


        <TextView
         
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="492dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
            android:text="TEXT VIEW"
            android:textColor="#2955D8"
            android:letterSpacing="0.03"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <EditText
          
            android:layout_width="326dp"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="201dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
            android:ems="10"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: android:background = "#ffffff" ?

Comment: а вообще у EditText есть поле hint - оно выводится когда нет текста в виджете. Так же можно порекомендовать вариант этого виджета из Material Design - там будет все именно в таком стиле

Comment: @ Style-7, тот единственный вариант, что я нашла в  Material Design - там немного не так

Comment: поверьте, что вам лучше использовать "немного не так"

Comment: @Style-7, верю:)

Answer (score 0):

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other.

По простому это означает, что `FrameLayout` должен содержать всего одного потомка, иначе будут проблемы с отображением. У вас внутри `FrameLayout` 2 потомка, которые как раз и накладываются друг на друга.

Вам надо внутри `FrameLayout` вписать 1 `LinearLayout` в вертикальным порядком следования и внутри него вписать свой `TextView` и `EditText`, примерно так:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1280dp"
    android:layout_height="720dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
          <TextView ....>
          <EditText ....>             
    </LinearLayout>
 <FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Вы забыли вводное слово Generally, FrameLayout часто применяется с несколькими "потомками".

Comment: @Barmaley♦,  и какой параметр использовать, что бы установить textView поверх  LinearLayout? не marginTop и не paddingTop ?

Comment: Что значит поверх? выше по вертикали или выше по слою?